# bash script: meaning of while read in a simple script that use inotifywait

Tags: bash, while-loop, inotify

```
#!/bin/sh
inotifywait -qme CREATE --format '%w%f' /tmp/watch | while read f; 
do 
ln -s "$f" /tmp/other/; 
done
```

I've found this script looking for something that react to filesystem event doing a specific job. The script works perfectly what i don't understand is the meaning of while read f;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's capturing the output of your `inotifywait` command and parsing it line by line, assigning each line in turn to `f` in the `while` statement.

That particular `inotifywait` command continuously monitors the `/tmp/watch` directory and outputs the full path name when an entry is created.

The `while` loop then processes each each of those file names and creates a symbolic link to it in the `/tmp/other/` directory.

Here's an example script showing the `while read` in action:

```
pax> printf "1\n2\n3 4\n" | while read f ; do echo "[$f]" ; done
[1]
[2]
[3 4]
```